# Trouble with Facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a unique and different problem on my wordpress site with facebook open graph

The site's home page is perfectly understood by the facebook open graph debugger ([link for reference](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.glideidea.com)).

But article page of the site, show error on the facebook's open graph debugger ([link for reference](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.glideidea.com/2012/04/25/science-of-india-rig-veda/)).

Following error is observed when a article link of my site is posted to facebook object debugger:

1. `Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.`
2. ```
   Graph API:
   {
       "error": {
           "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
           "type": "OAuthException",
           "code": 1
       }
   }
   ```

and the scraper is unable to load any data i.e. blank page.

Anyone who can, please help me with this matter, I have a strong suspicion that it is some plugin that messes things up on the articles and not on the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

I had a problem with a wordpress plugin (SEO ALRP PLUGIN) that I was using at that time. Be very cautious while checking the options given to you by Open Graph Protocol Wordpress plugins.

Comment: Please add more detail then mark it as your answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last week in Chrome and FF. It resolved itself on its own after ~24 hours. I'd say work on something else today and try it again tomorrow.

I think the FB engineers are tweaking the dev tools and occasionally breaking stuff along the way.

If you really need to work on it today, you could try the beta stack and see if that works better for you: https://developers.beta.facebook.com/

Comment: I am working on this problem from months now, got no answer so posted it today.

Comment: GOT IT SOLVED, I HAD MISCONFIGURED MY SEO ALRP PLUGIN